# Primefaces p:media not showing youtube video

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces p:media component

```
<p:media id="youTubeMedia"    value="#{graffiticontroller.selectedYouTubeURL}" width="405"   height="144" player="flash" />
```

the generated html is

```
<object height="144" width="405" data="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY0PBoDlHMI" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

the problem is that when the url is like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY0PBoDlHMI , the   youtube video does not show up . I just see a white box.
but if I alter the url to be http://www.youtube.com/v/yY0PBoDlHMI  the video shows up.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it reading this post http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=346

I copied the top link of my youtube video and applied some format.

For example if this is the original link of your video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ. 
The first thing you need to do is to replace "watch?" by "/" also you have replace the following "=" by "/" at the end you append this text to your link:

```
&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;
```

At the end you will get a link like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/fJ9rUzIMcZQ&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;
```

And now you can use your p:media

```
<p:media value="https://www.youtube.com/v/fJ9rUzIMcZQ&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;" width="600" height="" player="flash"/>
```

Comment: I forgot to add height

Answer (score -2):

put url in this way `http://www.youtube.com/watch/v/yY0PBoDlHMI` It will work...

Comment: I formatting the URL as 'code' so it isn't a clickable link, since you didn't mean that to be a link for someone to literally click on.